# InteractiveMarker sort of inertia?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there an easy way of implement a sort of inertia for `visualization_msgs::InteractiveMarker`?

I'm dealing with a MOVE_ROTATE InteractiveMarker in rviz and it is simple to move it too fast causing unexpected behaviour in my application. I think I could handle it with a saturation in the marker callback and a subsequent update of the pose of the marker with the satured value, but is there a neater way of accomplishing such a behaviour?

Thank you all.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219257/interactivemarker-sort-of-inertia?/) by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2015-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've made this rough workaround which does not represent the property of inertia, but works in a similar way:

```
class Class {
 public:
  ...
 private:
  interactive_markers::InteractiveMarkerServer *interactive_marker_server_;
  geometry_msgs::Pose marker_pose_;  // initialized in the constructor
  ...
}

void Class::interactiveMarkerCallback(const visualization_msgs::InteractiveMarkerFeedbackConstPtr &feedback) {
  // avoids too fast changes in the interactive marker pose (especially for its orientation)
  interactiveMarkerGuidance(feedback->pose, marker_pose_);  // marker_pose_ is updated every callback
  interactive_marker_server_->setPose(feedback->marker_name, marker_pose_, feedback->header);
  interactive_marker_server_->applyChanges();
}

void Class::interactiveMarkerGuidance(const geometry_msgs::Pose &target, geometry_msgs::Pose &current) {
  tf::Pose current_pose, target_pose;
  tf::poseMsgToTF(current, current_pose);
  tf::poseMsgToTF(target, target_pose);

  // distance and theta represent the arrow from current to target pose (the one given by the mouse position)
  double distance = tf::tfDistance(current_pose.getOrigin(), target_pose.getOrigin());
  double distance_sat = saturation(distance, marker_dist_min_, marker_dist_max_);
  double theta = std::atan2(target.position.y - current.position.y, target.position.x - current.position.x);

  // angle represents the rotation of the MOVE_ROTATE interactive marker
  double current_roll, current_pitch, current_yaw, target_roll, target_pitch, target_yaw;
  tf::Matrix3x3(current_pose.getRotation()).getRPY(current_roll, current_pitch, current_yaw);
  tf::Matrix3x3(target_pose.getRotation()).getRPY(target_roll, target_pitch, target_yaw);
  double angle = angles::shortest_angular_distance(current_yaw, target_yaw);
  double angle_sat = saturation(angle, marker_steer_min_, marker_steer_max_);

  tf::Transform transform;  // the transform with no saturated values would produce the default marker behaviour
  transform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(distance_sat*std::cos(theta - current_yaw), distance_sat*std::sin(theta - current_yaw), 0));
  transform.setRotation(tf::createQuaternionFromRPY(0, 0, angle_sat));
  current_pose *= transform;

  tf::poseTFToMsg(current_pose, current);
}

double Class::saturation(const double &value, const double &min, const double &max) {
  return std::min(std::max(value, min), max);
}
```

I have chosen not to add the interactive marker initialization to keep this answer as neat as possible. Anyway it is very similar to the one in the [Interactive Markers Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Interactive%20Markers%3A%20Basic%20Controls).

Any further comments or suggestions are welcome.

---

Originally posted by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) with karma: 217 on 2015-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0